# JQuery - more elegant coding solution for checking button state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just thinking out loud, is there a more elegant way for my coding solution. The code is working, but I've build a weather app with Freecodecamp.com and the task was to include a fahrenheit/celsius switch. So, there is an API which gives me the temperature, after I click a button, which gets my position. This temperature is in Fahrenheit. Before the output in html starts, the status of the switch should be checked and the temperature should be given out in Fahrenheit or Celsius. After I click the button again I can switch between Fahrenheit and Celsius Temperature.

In my mind, it was logical. Check the prop with IF (Celsius), else (Fahrenheit). Then after the state of the selector changes, the temperature should change accordingly.

My question is, can this code be optimized, I just started with Javascript and the code quality feels suboptimal. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I don't know why I get down voted, trolls?

Working Prototype [HERE](https://mkandut.github.io/No-Bullshit-Weather-App/)

JS:

```
<script>
function a() {
  var apiKey = "40683c3325e6ebb13cbf4331b7cc1f44";
  var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
  var lati;
  var longi;
  var icon;
  var data;
  var text;
  var tempFahrenheit;
  var tempCelsius;
  var textSummary;


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
          $("#out").html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }

  function showPosition(position) {
    var lati = position.coords.latitude;
    var longi = position.coords.longitude;
    $.getJSON(url + apiKey + "/" + lati + "," + longi + "?callback=?", function(data){
    //console.log(data);
      tempFahrenheit = data.currently.temperature;
      textSummary = data.currently.summary;

    // Different sayings based on icon API output
    var icon = data.currently.icon;
    switch(icon){
      case "clear-day":
        var text = "Cryyyssstaaal clear today. No clouds, not even the cloud service is working.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Sun.svg";
        break;
      case "clear-night":
        var text = "Clear night.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Moon.svg";
        break;
      case "rain":
        var text = "You need a shower? Now is your time. It's raining.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Umbrella.svg";
        break;
      case "snow":
        var text = "It's so cold. I'm farting snowflakes.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Snowflakes.svg";
        break;
      case "sleet":
        var text = "Falling ice cream or snow rain. Don't know";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Cloud-Snow-Sun-Alt.svg";
        break;
      case "wind":
        var text = "Flying umbrella ahead. WIND!?!?!?!";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Wind.svg";
        break;
      case "fog":
        var text = "Fucking Fog...";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Shades.svg";
        break;
      case "cloudy":
        var text = "Cloudy with a chance of ...";
        var icon ="img/SVG/Cloud.svg";
        break;
      case "partly-cloudy-day":
        var text = "Cloudy, but only above you. Sorry.";
        var icon ="img/SVG/Cloud-Sun.svg";
        break;
      case "partly-cloudy-night":
        var text = "Cloudy. Have you looked out the window today?";
        var icon ="img/SVG/Cloud-Moon.svg";
        break;
      case "hail":
        var text = "Be aware Golf balls made of ice are flying around.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Cloud-Hail.svg";
        break;
      case "thunderstorm":
        var text = "Thor angry. Thor making noise.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Cloud-Lightning.svg";
        break;
      case "tornado":
        var text = "That's .... have you seen it? That was your neighbours car. A tornado is close.";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Tornado.svg";
        break;
      default:
        var text = "no weather found. pls restart...";
        var icon = "img/SVG/Compass.svg";
        break;
    }


    $("#text").html(text);
    $("#icon").attr("src",icon);
    $("#summary").html(textSummary);



    if($("#tempSwitch").prop("checked") == true) {
        var tempCelsius = ((tempFahrenheit-32)/1.8).toFixed(2);
        $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius);
    } else {
        $("#temperature").html(tempFahrenheit);
    }
    $("#tempSwitch").change(function() {
      if($("#tempSwitch").prop("checked") == true) {
          var tempCelsius = ((tempFahrenheit-32)/1.8).toFixed(2);
          $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius);
      } else {
          $("#temperature").html(tempFahrenheit);
      }
    });
  })
};
```

};

EDIT: HTML Code

```
<h1>No Bullshit Weather App</h1>
<p>Click the button to check the weather</p>
<p>Alternative: If you have a window and can move your head, look outside to check the weather</p>

<p><button onclick="a()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>
<div id="temperature"></div>
  <input id="tempSwitch" type="checkbox" unchecked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Celsius" data-off="Fahrenheit">
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="summary"></div>
<img id="icon" src="">
```

Comment: need to share html code also , it seems like you are using change on button.

Comment: relevant html code added. Yes, I am using .change() on the checkbox button. Button is a toggle button via http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: @MarioK You should be able to do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2ary1q9y/

Comment: thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen. this was my first approach with a function, but this function would be within another function, which means the initial state of the button will only be checked if the function is called/somebody is changing the state of the button. I will put the whole code of the application here, so it's easier to understand in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do somthing like this? I could not test it because the api didnt seem to work on your github page.

```
var temp;

function checkTemp()
{
    //CELCIUS
    if($("#tempSwitch").checked)
    {
        temp = ((tempFahrenheit-32)/1.8).toFixed(2);
    } 
    //FAHRENHEIT
    else 
    {
        temp = tempFahrenheit;
    }
    //SET HTML
    $("#temperature").html(temp);

}
//ONCHANGE RUN FUNCTION CHECKTEMP
$("#tempSwitch").change(checkTemp);
//FIRST TIME RUN FUNCTION
checkTemp();
```

Comment: thanks, this gave me the right hint. I put it the if loop in a function, so at least a few lines lesser code. `var temp = function (){
   if($("#tempSwitch").prop("checked") == true) {
    var tempCelsius = ((tempFahrenheit-32)/1.8).toFixed(2);
    $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius);
   } else {
    $("#temperature").html(tempFahrenheit);
   } 
  }
  temp();
  $("#tempSwitch").change(temp);`

Comment: I just tested the api on the github page, it seems to work fine. There will only be an output if you allow the geolocation in your browser. Can you describe what is not working, pls?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I just rechecked ur github version, the first time i didnt get a popup for geo location. Now it works fine! Good luck with your project !

Comment: and in your new code: `if($("#tempSwitch").prop("checked") == true)` could be shortend to `if($("#tempSwitch").prop("checked"))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is a more elegant way but you can try the ternary operator:

```js
  tempFahrenheit = 0;
  
  $("#tempSwitch").change(function() {
      var checked = $(this).is(":checked")
          var tempCelsius = ((tempFahrenheit-32)/1.8).toFixed(2);
          $("#temperature").html(checked?tempCelsius:tempFahrenheit);
 
    }).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tempSwitch" type="checkbox" unchecked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Celsius" data-off="Fahrenheit">
<div id="temperature"></div>
```

Comment: multumesc, madalin. The problem is that initial state of the button will not be  given out.

Comment: trigger the change event using tigger

Comment: thanks, the solution works. .trigger() is a nice way to fire up an event.